# Count lines that are in the set of points

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I'm trying to solve a pretty complex problem with geometry and combinatorics.

Let's say we have given two integers $A, B$. Let us notice all the points with integer coordinates 
$$(0 < A,B < 3000)$$
$$(x, y) , (0 \leq x\leq A, 0\leq y\leq B) $$
Calculate how many lines contain at least two points with integer coordinates (described above)

**Example**
$$A = 1, B = 2$$ The result for this situation is 11. Here is picture with all the lines which fit in this coordinate system.

[image: All 11 lines]

**What I think for the solution**

My solution is as follows: With brute-force we can check for each pair of positive integers (i, j) such that $$(i \leq A, j\leq B)$$ $$GCD(i, j) = 1$$ where GCD is greatest common divisor. Now with math formula we can check how many lines are there which are moving in form of rectangle with sizes (i, j)

if we observe the upper example we have A+1 lines parallel to y-axis and B+1 lines parallel to y-axis, that is 2 + 3 = 5, if we observe the rectangles with sizes (1, 1) there are 4 lines with this rectangle, and (1,2) there are 2 lines with this rectangle, 2 + 3 + 4 + 2 = 11

Here is one more example, A = 2, B = 2, result = 20

Answer (score 1):

We have $A+1$ vertical lines.

For each fraction $\frac pq$ (in shortest terms) with $0\le p\le B$ and $1\le q\le A$, we have $((B\bmod p)+1)\cdot((A\bmod q)+1)$ lines with rising slope $\frac pq$ and the same number with falling slope.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you explain why this is always true.